# How to make it efficient - pandas apply (querying same dataframe from row values)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
mat['total'] = mat.apply(lambda row: mat[
                    (mat['Market'] == row['Market']) &
                    (mat['Brand'] == row['Brand']) &                   
                    (mat['Category'] == row['Category']) &                   
                    (mat['Facts'] == row['Facts']) &                 
                    (mat['Rolling Type'] == row['Rolling Type']) &                   
                    (mat['Flag'] == row['Flag']) &                  
                    (mat['Date'] <= row['Date']) &                  
                    (mat['Date'] >= (row['Date'] - relativedelta(months= 11)))]['value'].sum() , axis = 1)
```

The above code giving me the exact output i want. And i want to do it using groupby (i think it will be an efficient way)

I have this dataframe (mat) where for each row in data frame am filtering out dataframe with similar results of the row and checking if the date is in between the current date and 12 months before date and adding all filtered result.

Looking for an efficient way to do it? may be using groupby?

```
mat.groupby(['Market', 'Brand', 'Category', 'Facts', 'Rolling Type', 'Flag']).transform('sum')
```

The only thing am confused about is how to filter the date range here!

Comment: @BlackBear its taking time to do the operation over just 2000 rows. I had a similar situation earlier which i changed to transform and it did it in less than of a second. The problem is there i had no filter as of here date one

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post more details about your problem with example we can reproduce. You might find these links helpful: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you need to use `groupby` with `rolling`.  Please add some simplified, sample data to this problem and expected results.